# Android - Getting Current (Today) Date

Tags: android, date

Just a question , to get the current / today date in android. Is it more advisable to get it from a date picker or from a simple date format.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **System.currentTimeMillis()** which Returns the current time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you want that user selects the date from [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) then it is desirable to implement DatePicker. And if you want to display date directly in TextView then use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).